# You are not a sandbox user of this client. Error Codeigniter-Instagram api

Tags: php, authentication, codeigniter-2, instagram-api

In my `codeigniter` project I am trying to use `Instagram API` for log in.

[This](https://github.com/ianckc/CodeIgniter-Instagram-Library)
 is the library which I am using.

**But when going to the login page, it is showing error**

> {"code": 403, "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "error_message": "You are not a sandbox user of this client"}

The sample url is

```
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[client ID]&redirect_uri=[your url]&response_type=code
```

Why it is working like this? Any help could be appreciated

Comment: first of all generate access token: follow this: http://jelled.com/instagram/access-token

Comment: any success Arun?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per this error:

> {"code": 403, "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException",
>   "error_message": "You are not a sandbox user of this client"}

*First of all you need to create **Sandbox User**:*

**Step1:**

Login your account from here "*http://instagram.com/developer*" and than click on Manage Clients for creating New Client, make sure status of client is Sandbox.

**Step2:**

Fill all required fields and set `OAuth redirect_uri` field to "*http://localhost*" without using quotes. also unchecked `Disable implicit OAuth`

**Step 3:**

Now you can see the client id on Client Detail box, now you just need to generate Access Token for access API, you can use this URL:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[CLIENT_ID_HERE]&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=token
```

**You can check the status of Client from here:**
[image]

*Reference: http://jelled.com/instagram/access-token*

Comment: No success. I have did that steps but issue "You are not a sandbox user" didn't resolved

Comment: @argus disable implicit oauth

Comment: @Argus did you ever figure this out? Or did Instagram change their api?

Comment: @Rich: i used this API yesterday for my new client, and its working as mentioned in answer

Comment: @devpro, odd, I seem to be struggling with it today :/

Comment: @devpro 403:"OAuthForbiddenException"

I just did a sanity check with a new sandbox project and while I can verify the user that created the sandbox, I no longer seem able to invite another instagram account to use the sandbox app.

Comment: @Rich yes. And as a result I have posted my own answer in this topic. You can scroll a bit to see it.

Answer (score 3):

In such error case:

> {"code": 403, "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException",
>   "error_message": "You are not a sandbox user of this client"}

*You need to add that Instagram user to **`Sandbox Users`**:*

**Step1:**

Go *https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/*

Press **`Manage`**.

Press **`Sandbox`**.

**Step2:**

Type **`Instagram ID`** of user you getting that error add and press **`Save`**.
You will see **`pending`** in front of user you added.

**Step 3:**

Now you need to accept invitation.
Login into that Instagram account on the https://www.instagram.com.

Go to https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/sandbox_invites/

[image: http://joxi.ru/l2ZRDDPFzV9GK2.jpg]

Press **`Accept`**.

Done! Now should work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the already provided answers:

### Check the account you're logged in on Instagram

You cannot be logged in to account **A** and request a token for account **B**.

This is a simple answer, but I just spent 15 minutes figuring this out, because I'm logged in to different accounts under different Chrome windows.