# Is https://www.instagram.com/developer/ still working?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

My app was working fine previously, but now my client was not able to login to Instagram anymore. 
The error message was "you are not a sandbox user of this client". Anyone facing the same problem?

and i not able to register new client under "https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/". i just able to see the report issues button and Registration Disable button.

Comment: This might be the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632333/you-are-not-a-sandbox-user-of-this-client-error-codeigniter-instagram-api

Answer (score 0):

From Instagram developer website :

> Starting October 15, 2019, new client registration and permission review on Instagram API platform are discontinued in favor of the Instagram Basic Display API.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Instagram has stopped to register new clients for legacy API. I don't know why your previous client not able to login but from October 15, you can not create new clients for Instagram Legacy API. If you need to create new client for your app then you should migrate your app to Instagram Basic Display API or Instagram Graph API according to your needs.

Also they will cut off legacy API completely in March 2020

New API web site:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/